# How to solve dynamic xpath ( id chagned after exceute )

Tags: xpath, katalon-studio

I got problem such as :

- id="tabscontent:tabView:BWconent_0:j_idt6**70**"
- **After exceute**
- id changed = "tabscontent:tabView:BWconent_0:j_idt6**82**"
- **670** change **682**

Everyone know how to make : **contains()** or **starts-with()** or **ends-with()**

Please to help me 
Thank you so much

P/s : I mean using xpath id for Katalon Testcase

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to find solution using `contains()` or `starts-with()` or `ends-with()` or it is the exact opposite, you don't want to use any of those?

Comment: I mean : starts-with ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the beginning part of the `id` is static you can use `starts-with()` like this:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'tabscontent:tabView:BWconent_0:treeLeft_0:1:j_idt')]
```

The above XPath will return elements with `id` attribute value starts with "tabscontent:tabView:BWconent_0:treeLeft_0:1:j_idt"

Comment: Thank you har07 . Your help is easy & simple

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
TestObject myObject = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'a[id^="tabscontent:tabView:BWconent_0"]')
```

The `^="some text"` denotes "starts-with" for css selectors.

You will need to import TestObject and ConditionType classes. You can just press Ctrl+Shift+O in script mode and Katalon will do the rest.

Comment: Note: I added a tag for Katalon Studio, since it is mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Your tip is perfect . But please to show more detail .... How to use TestObject ( Step by step ) in Katalon ( I am not familiar with Css selectors )

Comment: You need to switch to script mode and add the line to your test script, anywhere *before* interacting with the test object. And please upvote if you found the answer useful.

Comment: Mate Mrse : I put inside Your Code into Script . Ctrl + Shift + O then Auto insert column "Binary Statement" . But not solve it . But I use simple //*[starts-with(@id...  Done